# Yii2, Bootstrap create header with out a input form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2

How can I make a header using `$form->field($model, 'date')` in Yii2 with out show a input text?

[image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: Can you elaborate it more?What are your expectations?

Comment: You want an input field in navbar ?

Comment: for example I have a date and a title. i want print label (from the yii model): value from database

Comment: try this `$model  =   new ModelName(); print_r($model->attributeLabels('attribute_name'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div><?= $form->getAttributeLabel('date') ?> :</div>
<div><?= $form->field($model, 'date') ?></div>
```

Comment: I get a error : Call to a member function getAttributeLabel() on a non-object

Comment: are you sure that your model has attributeLabels() function and it return label of 'date' ?!